# How to generate a unique id for same input id using Python?

Tags: python, uuid

I have a list of ids and I want to display a fake id for each id in my list using Python.

I used the uuid1() but when there is a duplicated id in my list the program stop and don't generate the same random id for same input id.

```
 print uuid.uuid1(data['user']['id']).int>>64
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. uuid4() is even worse it doesn't generate anything.

Comment: What is the specific purpose of `.int>>64` ?

Comment: it generate an integer id and size less than 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just hash your id :

```
import hashlib
id = 12
hashlib.sha256(str(id).encode()).hexdigest() # with python2.x you don't need to encode()
# => '6b51d431df5d7f141cbececcf79edf3dd861c3b4069f0b11661a3eefacbba918'
```

You'll have to store the correspondance somewhere though, because there is no way to retrieve the id from a hash.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solution worked for me but it's too long. Do you know how to shorten or convert to integer?

Comment: you could use md5 instead of sha256, md5 are only 32 chars long.
Check this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Comment: Thank you @Loïc, it's perfect now !

Answer (score 1):

from [python uuid doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1), uuid1 is dependent on current time.

You could use [uuid3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3) to have a reproducible uuid for the same input, by reusing the same namespace:

```
namespace = uuid.uuid4()
...
print uuid.uuid3(namespace, "1")
```